# How to keep same page in Flask

Tags: python, flask

this is a very simple code with Flask. Every time I click submit I go to another page and I lose my input field and my button.
I wonder HOW I can keep the same page and have just a refresh of the page when I have the output. Or if there is any other solution. Thank you

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request
app = Flask(__name__)
html = """
              <div class="form">
              <form action="{{url_for('sent')}}" method="POST">
                    <input title="Title" placeholder="Enter something" type="text" name="line" required> <br>
                <button class="go-button" type="submit"> Submit </button>
                </form>
          </div>
"""
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template_string(html)
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sent():
    line = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        line = request.form['line']
        return line
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect back to the original page after processing the input

Instead of

```
return line
```

You can

```
from flask import redirect, url_for

return redirect(url_for("index"))
```